# Using JOIN to find duplicates in another table taking too long

Tags: mysql, query-performance, join

Have a MySQL 8 database with the following tables.

**people**

```
id | mobile | name
```

**registrations**

```
id | people_id | other_stuff
```

I am trying to find the mobile number and the number of times it's duplicated by registrations. Some records in the `people` table do not have foreign records in the `registrations` table, so need to exclude them from our calculation.

If I do the following, the query runs relatively fast (500ms), but it excludes two or more registrations that have the same people_id

```
select mobile, count(mobile) as count from people where exists 
(select people_id from registrations where people_id = people.id) group by mobile having count > 1;
```

The following returns what I need, it returns the above but also takes into account `registrations` with the same `people_id`, but the problem is, this takes about 6 seconds for around ~250,000 rows in patients and registrations.

```
select mobile, count(mobile) as count from people inner join registrations on 
registrations.people_id = people.id group by mobile having count > 1;
```

I have indexes on the `mobile` and `people_id` columns.

Wondering if there's a faster way that returns exactly what I need.

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE for both tables. Show tables statistic (total, matched and returned rows amount). Provide execution plan for your queries. PS. Both queries are synthactically wrong and must fail while running as-is, correct them.

Comment: provide explain plan of both queries.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine that the first query would work.  The subquery needs `count` but that is not available until the entire query is finished.  The outer select can't move forward until the subquery provides the existence of each row.

Try to turn the entire query into a `JOIN`; no subquery.  In the `ON` you can test for one "people_id" being less than another -- this implies that there are two rows.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to find the mobile number and the number of times it's duplicated by registrations.

But the mobile number *isn't* duplicated.
Not according to what you've shown us.

The same *person* can have multiple *registrations*, but each person has one and only one mobile number (held in the people table).

Your query might as well be this:

```
select 
  mobile
, count( mobile ) as `count` 
from people 
group by mobile 
having count( mobile ) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried 2 queries which are working. Please try these queries, hopefully the performance will be better.

1.

```
SELECT p.mobile, COUNT(p.mobile)
FROM people p
INNER JOIN registrations r ON p.id = r.people_id
GROUP BY p.mobile
HAVING COUNT(p.mobile) > 1;
```

2. This query might be a little less proficient:

```
SELECT p.mobile, COUNT(p.mobile)
FROM people p, registrations r
WHERE p.id=r.people_id
GROUP BY mobile
HAVING COUNT>1
```